TypeError: Cannot read property 'NativeUnimoduleProxy' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I tried building my expo project.
But I have the error below.
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'NativeUnimoduleProxy' of undefined, js engine: hermes
Node: v21.6.2
expo: 0.17.13
Can anyone help me solve this error?
Thank you.
